# Python program to compute the sum of the terms of the series: 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + .... + n, where n is an input

Tags: python

```
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
total = 0
for j, i in enumerate(range(4, n + 4, 4)):
    if j % 2 == 1:
        i = -i
    total += i
print()
print("The sum is: %s"%(total))
```

Possible to use the same format as this code:
For example, if n = 256, the program sums 1 + 2 + 4 +
8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128 + 256 and displays the result 511

Comment: Will n be a power of two?

Comment: Enter the value of n: 32
The sum is 63 I messed up the example

Comment: What would happen if n is 31? What should the code do?

Comment: Assuming it stops if the iteration exceeds `n` (so `256` through `511` would all be equivalent), `(1 << n.bit_length()) - 1` would cover all non-negative numbers, and `(1 << n.bit_length()) - 1 if n >= 0 else 0` would cover negative too.

Comment: This looks like homework and also as if the teacher wants to test if you are smart. So far you won't get the extra point for that.

Comment: `n` is powers of 2. You could use `for i in itertools.count()`, which counts up from 0, use that as a power of two and keep track of a sum. In fact you could put it all in `sum(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `n` is a power of two,

```
print(2*n - 1)
```

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: No, their input is itself the largest power appearing in the series.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python solution:

```
sum(2**x for x in range(1 + int(math.log(n, 2))))
```

Here's a `numpy` solution:

```
np.sum(2**np.arange(1 + np.log2(n)))
```

Here's an `itertools` solution:

```
sum(2**x for x in itertools.islice(itertools.count(), 1 + int(math.log(n, 2))))
```

Comment: Beware of floating-point rounding errors. You can't expect `int(math.log(2**k, 2))` to be `k`, in general. It could be `k-1`. (On my machine, `math.log(2**2955, 2)` gives `2954.9999999999995`, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

In your series the next term =previous term * 2, So to find sum of this series ,we can keep track of previous term.

```
n=int(input("Enter n: "))
previous_term=1
total=0
while(previous_term<=n):
     total=total+previous_term
     previous_term=previous_term*2

print("The sum is: %s"%(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def main(number=2):
    Final = [0]
    for i in range(10):
        Final.append(number << i)
    print(Final)

main()
```

Comment: The result of a summation should not be an array.